# Составить запрос по удалению нескольких записей из одной таблицы со всеми связями в других таблицах

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ситуация такая :

Есть таблица, допустим **MainTable**. В ней есть *main_table_id* в качестве первичного ключа и много записей.

Есть несколько таблиц, допустим Table_1, Table_2, Table_3. Во всех этих таблицах есть вторичный ключ *main_table_id*.

Есть процедура удаления записей из **MainTable** и всех связанный записей в Table_1, Table_2, Table_3 через *main_table_id* такого вида:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_deleteMainTable
@main_table_id int
AS
DELETE FROM Table_1
    WHERE main_table_id=@main_table_id
DELETE FROM Table_2
    WHERE main_table_id=@main_table_id
DELETE FROM Table_3
    WHERE main_table_id=@main_table_id

DELETE FROM MainTable
    WHERE main_table_id=@main_table_id
RETURN 0
```

Как и что лучше использовать чтобы удалить сразу много записей по схожему признаку? Например выбрать все записи из **MainTable** где какое-нибудь поле содержит, например цифры 2019 (допустим в **MainTable** есть столбец *year* и в нем содержаться даты и надо удалить все записи за 2019 год).

Интересует как составить запросы, то есть, например, выгрузить список *main_table_id*, а потом в цикле вызывать хранимую процедуру удаления *sp_deleteMainTable* или что-то в этом роде...

Comment: у вас какая то нелюбовь к каскадным удалениям стандартными средствами, или зачем это все?

Comment: Есть программа-клиент, в которой можно удалить одну запись. Я запустил profiler и отследил хранимку которая осуществляет удаление. Нужно удалить сразу много записей, программа-клиент не способна это сделать. Вот я и спрашиваю совета как удобнее это сделать это средствами mssql. Погуглю про каскадные средства, а стандатные средства, вы имеете ввиду средства sql server managment studio или подобных?

Comment: ну дак оставьте эту процедуру пустой, дабы не порушить программу клиент, если исходники отсутствуют, и настройте каскадные удаления в свойствах внешних ключей.

Comment: стандартные средства это внешний ключ с обеспечением целостности, когда вы определяете связь между двумя таблицами, то одним из свойств является действия СУБД при удалении строки основной таблицы. Среди этих действий будут 1) ничего не делать  2) установить значение ключа во внешней таблицы в null 3) удалить строку зависимой таблицы.
вот это вам и надо сделать для всех связей - `on delete cascade`

Comment: спасибо, изучу-попробую на бекапе.